# FFmpeg: Cutting 3 seconds at the beginning of a video leaves 5 seconds blank

Tags: ffmpeg, editing, keyframes

I have an MKV video, and want to cut the first 3 seconds. I tried with FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i /input.mkv -ss 00:00:3.0 -c copy -t 00:09:58.0 output.mkv
```

But the result (when played in VLC) is that there are 5 seconds blank video with the original sound, and after that, the video shows.

I think it has something to do with a missing keyframe at the beginning. So I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i /input.mkv -ss 00:00:3.0 -c copy -t 00:09:58.0 -force_key_frames 00:00:00.000 output.mkv
```

But this has no effect - same result.

How can I cut a video properly so that it begins exactly where cut?

Comment: Replace `-t` with `-to`

Comment: @Marware nope, that just chnages if the time is a duration or end time.

Comment: I think I found the answer here: https://superuser.com/questions/138331/using-ffmpeg-to-cut-up-video  I need to put `-ss` in front of `-i` with some more time. `ffmpeg -ss 00:08:00 -i Video.mp4 -ss 00:01:00 -t 00:01:00 -c copy VideoClip.mp4`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered in FFmpeg's [Seeking](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking) wiki page.
The behavior is expected: If the time hits to a space between 2 key frames, it copies only audio up to the next keyframe and fills the video with black.

There are some methods to get also the beginning.

- One is to overlay the copied part with few seconds of re-encoded original.
- Or, simply, seek to a bit earlier frame.
- Or, find the previous keyframe and clip from that.
- Or, reencoding the whole clip.

It's a bit pity that FFmpeg (AFAIK) doesn't have a feature for this built in.